# Change base url in codeigniter, issue wampserver?

Tags: php, codeigniter, wampserver, configure

I have a codeigniter project.

I am using wampserver, index page is working fine.

I changed the base url to

```
http://localhost:8027/test_proj/04_04/
```

in config file but it keeps redirecting to

```
http://localhost:8027/index.php/magazine/add
```

the base directory, what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: What routes have you set up?

Comment: Thats what i have in my routes

$route['default_controller'] = "magazine";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: I guess its fine as i defined base_url already and now my default controller is this one, magazine.

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file? If you do, what does it look like?

Comment: Before doing anything else, create a Virtual Host for your project to run in, then things like base_url will work properly

Comment: No i dont have any .htaccess file.

Comment: You should have .htaccess file and config.php should be configured to remove "index.php"